# Configure capybara to trust all SSL Certificates

Tags: ruby, ssl, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I'm having some trouble working out how to get Capybara (1.1.1) to autoaccept SSL certificates on Chrome.

This is my current Capybara configuration

```
Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.app_host = 'http://some.host.com'
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium

Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
```

I have read about the -trustAllSSLCertificates flag but I'm not sure how to apply this when running Selenium using Capybara.

Answer (score -1):

This will do it with firefox:

```
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
    profile.assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer = false
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :profile => profile)
  end
```

Comment: The question specifically mentions Chrome ... so an answer for FF is not really useful :(